# Is it okay for prepositional phrases to remain when a sentence changes into a passive form?

Tags: passive-voice

Context: I ate pizza today. I put pizza on the **table**, and I sat on the **chair**. Then, I ate pizza.

I want to change “I ate pizza on the chair” into a passive form.

Is “Pizza was eaten on the chair” a correct expression in this context? Or is “pizza was eaten on the table” correct one?

Comment: Even the active form, "I ate pizza on the chair", does not sound like something a native speaker would say.  It would be more natural to say "I ate pizza sitting on the chair."

Comment: Where is: I ate pizza at the table, in the kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

I think since pizza is food and most of the food is eaten on tables so I would say the second one is more accurate, that is: a pizza was eaten on the table.

src: [needgrammar.com/list-of-phrasal-prepositions](https://www.needgrammar.com/grammar/list-of-phrasal-prepositions.html)

Comment: What does “more accurate” mean? In this **context**, “a pizza was eaten on the chair” is also fine?

Comment: @Iloveeverybody Your example reads weird, it seems that the pizza that was eaten was laid (put) on the chair, people sit on chairs they don't eat food off them. If you wanted to say that you were sitting on the chair then you need to change things around but the passive voice here is totally irrelevant here and only makes you sound detached and cold.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thank you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I always eat pizza on a plate - sometimes on my neighbours (if they pay) . normally on a Tuesday - often on holiday - on the hoof (if I'm in a hurry) - on an impulse (if I happen to be passing a pizzeria) - and I eat it off and on - on odd occasions - but never on a Sunday. I also eat it "off a table". What are we talking about here?

Comment: Detective: "A pizza was eaten on this chair. Presumably, the perp was sitting on the floor". But what a stretch that is.

Comment: @WS2 I understand your point but a year later,  eating a pizza on a chair  is still a little off.  If it has to be passivised then  "The meal  *was eaten* while standing up/sitting down"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I wasn't really making any point. I'm as bemused as you are by the idea of "eating pizza on a chair".